# Django autocomplete light, taggit and the admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin, django-taggit, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to use autocomplete_light and taggit both on an admin form.

I've read the docs on integrating autocomplete light and taggit [here](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-autocomplete_light.contrib.taggit_tagfield), 
and the docs on integrating autocomplete light in the admin [here](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html). But there seems to be little (or no) discussion on doing both at the same time.

what I've got so far.

In `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from taggit.models import TagBase, GenericTaggedItemBase


class MyTag(TagBase):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 250, blank = True, null = True)

class MyTagThroughModel(GenericTaggedItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(MyTag, related_name = "tagged_items")

class MyModel(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    ...
    tags = TaggableManager(through = MyTagThroughModel)
```

In `autocomplete_light_registry.py`:

```
import autocomplete_light
from models import MyTag
autocomplete_light.register(MyTag)
```

How am I meant to structure `admin.py`?

If this was a non-admin form, the field would be given as:

```
tags = TagField(widget = TagWidget('MyTagAutocomplete'))
```

If this was a non-taggit admin form, I would add the following to the admin model class:

```
form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(MyTag)
```

How can I combine the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How am I meant to structure admin.py?

Here's an example to autocomplete Tags. It shows you how autocomplete_light and taggit work on admin and non-admin forms.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**

```
import autocomplete_light
from taggit.models import Tag

autocomplete_light.register(Tag)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
import autocomplete_light
from autocomplete_light.contrib import taggit_tagfield
from models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = taggit_tagfield.TagField(widget=taggit_tagfield.TagWidget('TagAutocomplete'))
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'tags': autocomplete_light.TextWidget('TagAutocomplete'),
        }
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
import autocomplete_light
from models import MyModel
from forms import MyModelForm

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
    model = MyModel

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from models import MyModel
from forms import  MyModelForm

class CreateMyModel(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from views import CreateMyModel

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^create/$', CreateMyModel.as_view()),
)
```

The [quick docs](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quick.html) seem to be more straightforward to understand than the docs you were looking at.

Comment: Thanks. This got it to work. Incidentally, I'm using `url(r'autocomplete/', include('autocomplete_light.urls')),` in `urls.py`, but I'm sure there are other ways of doing it.

Comment: Actually... this still causes a problem. It works fine when I add a new record, but when I go to edit an existing record I get:

`Error during template rendering

In template (...)/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet'`

Comment: I just edited my answer and changed forms.py and admin.py. This should let you edit records. I still see an issue with the tags loaded in a different format, I will look into it, but at least this give you a place to start.

Comment: Thanks - that does it. Having seen the alternative, I prefer the `MultipleChoiceWidget` than the `TextWidget` - but it seems like autocomplete_light doesn't support that... yet.

Comment: There are now some docs on Auto Complete Light and Taggit integration found here: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/taggit.html

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [django-taggit-autosuggest](https://bitbucket.org/fabian/django-taggit-autosuggest/) instead.

[image: Tag Autocomplete Autosuggest on Django]

It works best with the [django-grapelli](http://grappelliproject.com/) admin skin.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to use  django-taggit-autosuggest with djang 1.10 but i am having trouble with url patterns...  urlpatterns = patterns('taggit_autosuggest.views',
NameError: name 'patterns' is not defined  .

Comment: django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated, update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.